# OSX Mavericks and Windows 7 missing files

Tags: networking, windows-7, mac-osx, network-share

I have in a local Mac mini server running Mavericks which is acting as a file server for two windows 7 clients

The files on the server are mainly images and are shared via SMB. Whenever I try to view certain folders of through a client image editor or ftp client only a few appear. ALL files can be viewed in Windows Explorer but not via any application browse facility.

The permissions on the OSX image folders are all 777 and the owner is the same user that I use to connect the network shares from windows. What makes this stranger is that the only files viewable in a couple of the 70 or so folders are those named 1.jpg , 100.jpg , 1010.jpg , 1101.jpg etc? Filezila reports an error stating the LC_CTYPE is not set and certain files can't be decoded.

Comment: The title of this question is “OSX Mavericks and Windows 7 missing files” but then you say, “The permissions on OSX are all 777 and the owner is the same user that I use to connect the network shares from windows.” Pitch perfect example of why you should never use 777 permissions for any reason. Chances are someone accidentally deleted the  files because it doesn’t seem like there is any security on any of your servers.

Comment: Sorry the permissions on the images folders are 777. The files exist on the server and can be viewed on the client machines in explorer just not flie browsing through apps ( such as Picassa, Filezilla )

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the solution. The problem lies with an issue in SMB2 running on OSX Mavericks.

The answer is to disable SMB2 and SMB3 in the client machine ( in the case below for Windows 7 )

```
sc.exe config lanmanworkstation depend= bowser/mrxsmb10/nsi 
sc.exe config mrxsmb20 start= disabled
```

Sourced from this article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2696547 under the section 'How to enable or disable SMB protocols on the SMB client'

Comment: I think that's more of a workaround than a solution, but if it works for you then I won't knock that. In the longer term though, if this is an issue with SMB file serving then its more likely to be an issue with the server (and hence hopefully fixed in a later patch for Mavericks) than a client issue. As SMB 2 & 3 offer substantial improvements, it might be worth keeping this in mind and trying again after the next major OSX patch.

Comment: Yes this is true I wont accept the answer then.